# TestFlightapp.com will shutdown on 2/26/2015

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, xcode6

As noticed that TestFlight going to be shutdown. So anymore it will be available or only on iTunesConnect, i tried to login with connect Itunes by Enterprise account  , but we  got warning "Your Apple ID isn't enabled for iTunes Connect" but when i tried to login with connect Itunes by developer account then it will connect,

so my problem is why it is connecting with Itunes when we are login with enterprises account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enterprise accounts cannot submit apps to the AppStore and as such cannot access that part of the developer portal. You don't need test flight to distribute apps if you have an enterprise account anyway. You can create ad hoc builds that will work on any device installed upon. Obviously you need to familiarise yourself with the Terms & Conditions i.e. it's a violation to distribute apps using an Enterprise License to any device that is outside of that Enterprise/Company.

Comment: ok this is fine , actually TestFlightapp.com will shutdown on 2/26/2015 ,then how can i send the build file to client

Comment: http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2011/01/21/1/how-to-distribute-your-ios-apps-over-the-air

Comment: but in test flight showing all the  functionality of test flight available in Itunes connect , but now i want to use itunes except of test flight

Comment: you can't with an enterprise account.